# How do i extend a constructor+method with optional arguments in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-audio-api

I want to extend the [`AudioBufferSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode)class so that i can support playback of the sound multiple times. I want to override both the constructor and the `start()`/`stop()` methods, but i don't know how to do that in the "correct" way since they have optional arguments and not all the defaults are provided on MDN ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/AudioBufferSourceNode), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start)). Coming from OOP languages i expected to find a more precise method signature so that i can build upon that, but i could only find native code.

So what's the most correct way to do that?

Comment: You can just pass through all arguments unchanged using rest+spread syntax or `arguments`+`apply`.

Comment: Subclassing the builtin class is probably not the correct way to do that.

Comment: @Bergi if i override the methods declaring `start(a, b, c)` and then calling `super.start(a, b, c)` aren't the parameters in my overridden method mandatory, while they remain optional in the super method? If this is not the correct way to do it, how do you suggest i implement that?

Comment: No, that doesn't make them mandatory (except for people looking at your function's arity), you just pass through `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to extend the `AudioBufferSourceNode` you could do it like this:

```
class MyABSN extends AudioBufferSourceNode {

    constructor (context, ...args) {
        super(context, ...args);
    }

    start (...args) {
        super.start(...args);
    }

    stop (...args) {
        super.stop(...args);
    }

}
```

In every function `args` will be an array that contains the optional function arguments. The fact that I named this array `args` is just a convention. You can choose a different name if you like.

As an example, if you call start on an instance of your class like this `myABSN.start(0, 2)` the `args` array would be `[ 0, 2 ]` and the method on `super` would be called as `super.start(0, 2)`.

You might want to override the `connect()` and `disconnect()` methods as well to keep track of the connections.